# Access to Microsoft eDiscovery with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access to O365 (Security & Compliance) eDiscovery with Microsoft Graph API ?.. as far as microsoft flow does not allow it either.. any idea how to execute search contents or use Data subject requests with API ?

thank you

Comment: Hi, please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we do not have this capability available on Microsoft Graph. Please vote on this feature request on https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/ . I don't believe anyone has requested this yet so may need to create not vote up.